# Android draw rect round with drawPath and drawRoundRect result in different result

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

When I draw path in android, the line seems too thin. So I made a experiment: 
draw a round rect using `drawPath` and using `drawRoundRect`.
here is my code:

```
//setPaint
mStrokeWidth = 1;
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);   
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

//draw using drawRoundRect
mStrokeWidth = 1;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect bounds = getBounds();
    mRect.set(bounds.left + mStrokeWidth / 2,
                  bounds.top + mStrokeWidth / 2,
                  bounds.right - mStrokeWidth / 2,
                  bounds.bottom - mStrokeWidth / 2
                );
    canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, 10, 10, mPaint);
}

//draw using drawPath
mStrokeWidth = 1;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      Rect bounds = getBounds();
      mRect.set(bounds.left + mStrokeWidth / 2,
                      bounds.top + mStrokeWidth / 2,
                      bounds.right - mStrokeWidth / 2,
                      bounds.bottom - mStrokeWidth / 2
                    );
      Path path = new Path();
      path.addRoundRect(mRect, 10, 10, Path.Direction.CCW);
      canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

here is the result:

[image]

the left is using drawRoundRect and the right using drawPath
you can see that the left is thicker than the right. I want to know what  caused the phenomenon?

Comment: interesting ... can you try to force Antialias on or off in both places with `mPaint.setAntiAlias( true );` and see if that's the problem? just guessing!

Comment: already both set mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);